# Is updating the value of a Map by mutating its reference bad practice?

Tags: java, functional-programming, hashmap, immutability

I have code similar to this all around a codebase I'm working on:

```
Map<String, Map<Object, Integer>> mapOfMap = new HashMap<>();

Map<Object, Integer> mapA = mapOfMap.computeIfAbsent(keyParam, k -> new HashMap<>());
mapA.put(objectParam, mapA.getOrDefault(objectParam, 0) + 1);
```

This way, we have updated the value of 'keyParam' in the first map without a direct call to the put() method.

I tend to prefer when code is explicit and would typically write a plain call to 'put'. However, I'm wondering if I'm overthinking it and this conciseness is something we gain for having object references?  Can this be written in a similarly concise way in Java that pretends the objects are immutable?

Comment: There are some conflicting variable names that make it very hard to parse what this is supposed to demonstrate.  Are `mapOfMapA` and `mapOfMap` supposed to be the same?  In any event, nothing about this code looks at all unusual; there's nothing weird about mutability going on.

Comment: The methods `put()` and `computeIfAbsent` (and `putIfAbsent()`) are completely different things. If you replace the compute with a put, the meaning of the code becomes completely different. In this case it doesn't, because it's a synthetic example working with empty maps. It's very unclear what you want to pretend to be immutable, the maps?

Comment: @LouisWasserman The issue discussed is whether it is bad style to have mutable objects as **values** in a map.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks, I'm aware that they're different things.  I'm not talking about replacing the compute with a put . I'm talking more about adding another  'put' on the last line to show that mapOfMap has been updated, instead of just relying on the mutability.

Comment: That would not be idiomatic code. It would only be confusing, not improve readability. It's not bad style to have mutable objects as *values*, but it can be dangerous to have mutable objects as *keys* if one isn't careful. Maps of maps with `computeIfAbsent` OTOH is idiomatic code, so no need for extra puts, no need to worry about mutability (well, besides the normal worries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be, but not in this case.

In this case, the code knows what it's doing, presumably. It's maybe even inteded for the object to be mutable. The only way to get around this is copy the value object, mutate it, then put it again. This could be quite costly in some programs, also I am not sure if the style is really better, I don't feel it would be more readable or always less error prone. It depends on how much you believe in immutable objects in general.

Where it does become a problem is when things are mutated that should not be. But this has nothing to do with maps per se.

For example:

In this [issue on github](https://github.com/lucidworks/auto-phrase-tokenfilter/issues/8), a reference to a list that is supposed to be immutable gets passed to a part of the code that does mutate it, leading to at least a memory leak in this case.